# How do I make a 16 bit Adder-Subtractor with Overflow detection using VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I am using ModelSim to implement a 16 bit adder subtractor with overflow detection.

This is what I have so far. I am not sure how to implement a subtractor into the adder. I know it has to do with the two's complement but I don't know how to do it in VHDL. I'm also not sure how to do overflow detection.

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity ONE_BIT_ADDER is
  port( a, b, cin : in STD_LOGIC; 
       sum, cout : out STD_LOGIC );
end ONE_BIT_ADDER;

architecture ADDER of ONE_BIT_ADDER is 
begin

  sum <= (not a and not b and cin) or
         (not a and b and not cin) or
         (a and not b and not cin) or
         (a and b and cin);

  cout <= (not a and b and cin) or
          (a and not b and cin) or
          (a and b and not cin) or
          (a and b and cin);

end ADDER;

LIBRARY IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity SIXTEEN_BIT_ADDER is
  port( a, b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        cin : in STD_LOGIC;
        sum  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        cout, overflow : out STD_LOGIC );
end SIXTEEN_BIT_ADDER;

architecture BEHAVIORAL of SIXTEEN_BIT_ADDER is
component ONE_BIT_ADDER
  port( a, b, cin : in STD_LOGIC; 
        sum, cout : out STD_LOGIC );  
end component;

signal c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15 :    STD_LOGIC;
begin


b_adder0: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(0), b => b(0), cin => cin, sum => sum(0), cout => c1);
b_adder1: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(1), b => b(1), cin => c1, sum => sum(1), cout => c2);
b_adder2: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(2), b => b(2), cin => c2, sum => sum(2), cout => c3);
b_adder3: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(3), b => b(3), cin => c3, sum => sum(3), cout => c4);
b_adder4: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(4), b => b(4), cin => c4, sum => sum(4), cout => c5);
b_adder5: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(5), b => b(5), cin => c5, sum => sum(5), cout => c6);
b_adder6: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(6), b => b(6), cin => c6, sum => sum(6), cout => c7);
b_adder7: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(7), b => b(7), cin => c7, sum => sum(7), cout => c8);
b_adder8: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(8), b => b(8), cin => c8, sum => sum(8), cout => c9);
b_adder9: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(9), b => b(9), cin => c9, sum => sum(9), cout => c10);
b_adder10: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(10), b => b(10), cin => c10, sum => sum(10), cout => c11);
b_adder11: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(11), b => b(11), cin => c11, sum => sum(11), cout => c12);
b_adder12: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(12), b => b(12), cin => c12, sum => sum(12), cout => c13);
b_adder13: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(13), b => b(13), cin => c13, sum => sum(13), cout => c14);
b_adder14: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(14), b => b(14), cin => c14, sum => sum(14), cout => c15);
b_adder15: ONE_BIT_ADDER port map (a => a(15), b => b(15), cin => c15, sum => sum(15), cout => cout);



END BEHAVIORAL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use instances. Just declare 16 bit parameters and do your operation (add or subtract).
Assume that we have a parameter `operation` that shows the operation.

`operation = '0'` (add)

`operation = '1'` (subtract)

Now use the following code (for simplicity I removed cin from inputs) :

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_signed.ALL;

ENTITY ALU IS
   PORT(data1     : IN  std_logic_vector(15 DOWNTO 0);
        data2     : IN  std_logic_vector(15 DOWNTO 0);
        operation : IN  std_logic;
        result    : OUT std_logic_vector (15 DOWNTO 0);
        overflow  : OUT std_logic
   );        
END ALU;

ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF ALU IS
    SIGNAL result_temp : std_logic_vector(15 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
    result_temp <= (data1 + data2) WHEN (operation = '0') ELSE (data1 - data2);
    overflow    <= '1' WHEN (operation='0' AND data1(15)=data2(15) AND result_temp(15)/=data1(15)) or
                            (operation='1' AND data1(15)/=data2(15) AND result_temp(15)/=data1(15)) ELSE '0';
    result      <= result_temp;
END Behavioral;
```

An explanation about overflow :

When we add two **positive** parameters, we expect the result to be **positive**, otherwise we have overflow.

When we add two **negative** parameters, we expect the result to be **negative**, otherwise we have overflow.

When we subtract two parameters (the first parameter is **positive** and the second one is **negative**), we expect the result to be **positive**, otherwise we have overflow.

When we subtract two parameters (the first parameter is **negative** and the second one is **positive**), we expect the result to be **negative**, otherwise we have overflow.